# Throwing exception in constructor of EJB web service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I have an EJB Web Service.  I have created custom fault classes that are thrown by web service methods and this works great.  My client catches those custom exceptions and handles them fine.  The issue I've run into is that if an exception happens in the constructor of the bean and I throw my custom exception the client doesn't receive my custom exception it receives the following:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
at $Proxy34.getLots(Unknown Source)
```

My question is: can custom exceptions be thrown in the constructor of an EJB and be received from the client?  If so what am I doing wrong.

My code:

EJB Constructor

```
public LotManagement() throws LotManagementException
{
    try {
        pm = new PromisManager();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LotManagement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        FaultBean LotManagementFaultBean = new FaultBean();
        throw new LotManagementException(ex.getMessage() + "\n\n" + propMan.getProperty("ContactMessage"), LotManagementFaultBean, ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

Fault Bean

```
package com.onsemi.cim.exception;
import javax.xml.ws.WebFault;

@WebFault(name="LotManagementException")

public class LotManagementException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private FaultBean faultBean;

public LotManagementException() {
    super();
}

public LotManagementException(String message, FaultBean faultBean,
        Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    this.faultBean = faultBean;
}

public LotManagementException(String message, FaultBean faultBean) {
    super(message);
    this.faultBean = faultBean;
}

public FaultBean getFaultInfo() {
    return faultBean;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution can be that you try to catch the exception inside your constructor and handle all exceptions there. Come on an agreement with your client that you will either throw an exception or will send some custom error message like status 0/1 etc and based upon the response code they can decide to work accordingly.

Also I will encourage you not to throw even custom exception and try sending error messages because in future if for some reason you need to replace your custom error mechanism then you need to ask you client to do some changes accordingly.

Comment: The problem I see here is that it's the constructor of the web service, I don't see a way of even getting a message back to the client.  I would almost have to set a global variable in the constructor that the web service method would read to see that there had been an issue and then return the failure in the method.  This seems really hacky and messy to me.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is not a good idea to throw exceptions from constructors because different APIs (Like Spring) treat them differently. You are getting that error because when you get an exception from EJB constructor it throws CreateException.
So my opinion will be to check and possible remove the exception from constructor.

Comment: and how do you propose to solve the problem he has mentioned?